# JMX - Monitor process existence

Tags: java, jmx, process-monitoring

I want to be able to monitor a process's existence continuously and restart it if it had crashed or killed for any reason using JMX. Stopping and starting a process is not a probelm as the agent executes a script for it. I can monitor process's existence by implementing heartbeats between the agent and the monitored process but I am looking for something using JMX itself, if something exists?

Answer (score 0):

You can expose the component as a `JMX` managed resource.
Try to do the heartbeat.
If you get instanceNotFound from the managed bean server then it has crashed.

Comment: I just added a JMX operation called ping and started executing it periodically using java Timer.